# why a custom style does not override a previous defined style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a web page that adds first bootstrap.css and then custom.css. Both CSS files define a style called .container, this way:

bootstrap.css:

```
container {            /* line 1245 */
    max-width: 1170px; 
}
.container {           /* line 1082 */
    max-width: 970px;  
}
.container {           /* line 928 */
    max-width: 750px;  
}
.container {           /* line 759 */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

In custom.css:

```
.container {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

When run the application, style in line 1245 of bootstrap.css controls the width. When I disable it, the style in line 1082 is used. Finally, when I disable that, the style in line 928 is used. When I disable this latter, the definition in custom.css is used.

However, this same structure and CSS are in this page: https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html. In this page, the same definition works.

Please, don't suggest to use !important in custom.css, since if the same structure in the link above works, it means that something else is wrong.

If you are curious, this is how I include the CSS files:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/iCheck/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

And this is part of the body:

```
<body class="nav-md">
  <div class="container body">....</div>
</body>
```

What may be wrong?

Comment: hi.. override the max-width property in your custom css.. and give a try. set max-width:100%;

Comment: yes.. that works.. but I wonder why in the online site I gave the link, the custom.css works without defining the max-width

Comment: hi.. container in gird.less file have width property and bootstrap.css have max-width property. That's the reason when "width" was overridden in that site it worked. here you need to override the max-width property. ... hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Well a CSS file loads top to bottom. 
Line 1245 will be the last line that changes the container width property in the bootstrap.css file.

EDIT: Added an example. 
200px but max-width restricts it to be 50px since CSS runs top to bottom.

Another thing to keep in mind is that `max-width` will **always** override `width` whether or not it comes before it.

```css
.one {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
}
.three {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: violet;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container {           /* line 26 */
  max-width: 150px;  
}
.container {           /* line 29 */
  max-width: 100px;  
}
.container {            /* line 32 */
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"><p>50px</p></div>
<div class="two"><p>100px</p></div>
<div class="three"><p>150px</p></div>
<div class="container"><p>50px</p></div>
```

Comment: do you mean that the CSS processor loads all CSS files, line by line, storing them in some kind of buffer, and finally, the definition in the last line is used? This does not sound logic to me. Process should store the style definitions as they appear in the CSS files, using the same order.

Comment: @jstuardo The CSS spec states that a later rule always overrides an earlier rule with same specificity and target.

Comment: @jstuardo I added an example to come with my answer. Check out the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you write at bottom overrides previously written CSS.

Use **!important** with css to give it more priority.

Use hierarchy for highest priority:

```
.Parent1>.Parent2>.container
```